# Single word for Unit Price?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word or acronym for **Unit Price** ?
I would prefer a word over acronym.

I will be using the word to represent a data column in a database.

Comment: I'm not sure you can express the concept "unit price" in fewer words without losing some of the meaning.  The only word I can think of would be "price", but then you would lose the specificity of it being a price per unit.

Comment: What's wrong with UnitPrice or Unit_Price?

Comment: @jim I am trying to follow a predefined naming convention, where Camel cases and underscores are not allowed.

Comment: Then just name it *ppu* (price per unit) and complain about over-restrictive naming conventions if challenged.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about English but rather, about variable naming under abnormal constraints.

Comment: @HollyK Yup, I think "price" is the way to go. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jim how is it off topic ? single word request can't be off topic, even the website has a tag named single-word-request.

Comment: @StudentX You're asking for a name, not just any word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your purpose, I think `rate` would be adequate and sufficient:

> a fixed charge per unit of quantity:
>
> *a rate of 10 cents a pound.*
>
> [Reference: (see definition No. 3)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rate)

Answer (score -1):

A single word you can use is *rate*. The symbol used is *@*.